# SQL Count data with conditions on multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

So here is my simplified structure:
Company <- User <- Order <- Order status

I need to perform multiple counts of orders for each company. Each count can have its own filters by `order_status`. In return should be company's id and multiple counts.

Here is what I tried for one count, but I cannot combine it with others counts.

```
SELECT c.id as company_id, COUNT(o.id) as orders_count_total
    FROM companies c
    LEFT JOIN users u
        ON u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON
            c.id = o.users_company_id OR
           (
                u.id = o.users_id AND
                u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id AND
                o.users_company_id is NULL
            )
    JOIN orders_orderstatus o_status
        ON o.status_id = o_status.id AND NOT (o_status.slug IN ('slug1', 'slug2'))
GROUP BY company_id
```

Also in this case I miss all companies that don't have any orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm completely unsure of myself on this, so I have my finger on the "Delete" key prepared to nuke this answer if it's completely wrong, but can you do two left joins, one with each condition, and then coalesce?

```
SELECT
  c.id as company_id, COUNT(coalesce (o1.id, o2.id)) as orders_count_total
FROM
  companies c
  LEFT JOIN users u
      ON u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN orders o1
      ON c.id = o1.users_company_id
  left join orders o2 on
      u.id = o2.users_id AND
      u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id AND
      o2.users_company_id is NULL
  JOIN orders_orderstatus o_status
      ON coalesce (o1.status_id, o2.status_id) = o_status.id AND 
      NOT (o_status.slug IN ('slug1', 'slug2'))
GROUP BY company_id
```

Count should only count non-null results, so I would think this would work.

If not, how about the same coalesce in a CTE and then an inner join to the order status table?

```
with orders as (
  SELECT
    c.id as company_id, coalesce (o1.id, o2.id) as order_id
  FROM
    companies c
    LEFT JOIN users u
        ON u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN orders o1
        ON c.id = o1.users_company_id
    left join orders o2 on
        u.id = o2.users_id AND
        u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id AND
        o2.users_company_id is NULL
  where
    o1.id is not null or o2.id is not null
)
select
  o.company_id, count (o.order_id) as orders_count_total
from
  orders o
  JOIN orders_orderstatus o_status on
      o.order_id = o_status.id AND 
      NOT (o_status.slug IN ('slug1', 'slug2'))
GROUP BY company_id
```

I've had really bad experience with using "OR" conditions in the join, unless the original condition is highly selective -- yours doesn't appear to be, as you seem to want two completely distinct joins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it returns empty table

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the last `JOIN` is an inner join.  Once you use `LEFT JOIN`, you should continue with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.id as company_id, COUNT(o.id) as orders_count_total
FROM companies c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id
     orders o LEFT JOIN
     ON c.id = o.users_company_id OR
        (u.id = o.users_id AND
         u.belongs_to_company_id = c.id AND
         o.users_company_id is NULL
        ) LEFT JOIN
     orders_orderstatus o_status
     ON o.status_id = o_status.id AND 
        o_status.slug NOT IN ('slug1', 'slug2')
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Comment: But in this case I will have all orders and they will not be filtered by order_statuses